# How to insert numbers in words for the numeric value using triggers in sql?

Tags: sql-server

I need to get the amount in words automatically after I enter the amount in numeric.

eg: If I enter 2500, It should be automatically insert in the next field as Two thousand five hundred.

Is it possible in sql server pls guide with explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below function to Convert into the word:

```
        CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Currency_ToWords] (
            @Input Numeric (38) -- Input number with as many as 18 digits

        ) RETURNS VARCHAR(8000) 

        /*
        * Converts a integer number as large as 34 digits into the 
        * equivalent words.  The first letter is capitalized.
        *
        * Attribution: Based on NumberToWords by Srinivas Sampath
        *        as revised by Nick Barclay
        *
        * Example:
        select dbo.udf_Num_ToWords (1234567890) + CHAR(10)
              +  dbo.udf_Num_ToWords (0) + CHAR(10)
              +  dbo.udf_Num_ToWords (123) + CHAR(10)
        select dbo.udf_Num_ToWords(76543210987654321098765432109876543210)

        DECLARE @i numeric (38,0)
        SET @i = 0
        WHILE @I <= 1000 BEGIN 
            PRINT convert (char(5), @i)  
                    + convert(varchar(255), dbo.udf_Num_ToWords(@i)) 
            SET @I  = @i + 1 
        END
        *
        * Published as the T-SQL UDF of the Week Vol 2 #9 2/17/03
        ****************************************************************/
        AS BEGIN
        Declare @Number Numeric(38,0)
        set @Number = @Input
        Declare @Cents as int
        set @Cents = 100*Convert(money,(@Input - convert(Numeric(38,3),@Number)))
        DECLARE @inputNumber VARCHAR(38)
        DECLARE @NumbersTable TABLE (number CHAR(2), word VARCHAR(10))
        DECLARE @outputString VARCHAR(8000)
        DECLARE @length INT
        DECLARE @counter INT
        DECLARE @loops INT
        DECLARE @position INT
        DECLARE @chunk CHAR(3) -- for chunks of 3 numbers
        DECLARE @tensones CHAR(2)
        DECLARE @hundreds CHAR(1)
        DECLARE @tens CHAR(1)
        DECLARE @ones CHAR(1)

        IF @Number = 0 Return 'Zero'

        -- initialize the variables
        SELECT @inputNumber = CONVERT(varchar(38), @Number)
             , @outputString = ''
             , @counter = 1
        SELECT @length   = LEN(@inputNumber)
             , @position = LEN(@inputNumber) - 2
             , @loops    = LEN(@inputNumber)/3

        -- make sure there is an extra loop added for the remaining numbers
        IF LEN(@inputNumber) % 3 <> 0 SET @loops = @loops + 1

        -- insert data for the numbers and words
        INSERT INTO @NumbersTable   SELECT '00', ''
            UNION ALL SELECT '01', 'one'      UNION ALL SELECT '02', 'two'
            UNION ALL SELECT '03', 'three'    UNION ALL SELECT '04', 'four'
            UNION ALL SELECT '05', 'five'     UNION ALL SELECT '06', 'six'
            UNION ALL SELECT '07', 'seven'    UNION ALL SELECT '08', 'eight'
            UNION ALL SELECT '09', 'nine'     UNION ALL SELECT '10', 'ten'
            UNION ALL SELECT '11', 'eleven'   UNION ALL SELECT '12', 'twelve'
            UNION ALL SELECT '13', 'thirteen' UNION ALL SELECT '14', 'fourteen'
            UNION ALL SELECT '15', 'fifteen'  UNION ALL SELECT '16', 'sixteen'
            UNION ALL SELECT '17', 'seventeen' UNION ALL SELECT '18', 'eighteen'
            UNION ALL SELECT '19', 'nineteen' UNION ALL SELECT '20', 'twenty'
            UNION ALL SELECT '30', 'thirty'   UNION ALL SELECT '40', 'forty'
            UNION ALL SELECT '50', 'fifty'    UNION ALL SELECT '60', 'sixty'
            UNION ALL SELECT '70', 'seventy'  UNION ALL SELECT '80', 'eighty'
            UNION ALL SELECT '90', 'ninety'   

        WHILE @counter <= @loops BEGIN

            -- get chunks of 3 numbers at a time, padded with leading zeros
            SET @chunk = RIGHT('000' + SUBSTRING(@inputNumber, @position, 3), 3)

            IF @chunk <> '000' BEGIN
                SELECT @tensones = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 2, 2)
                     , @hundreds = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 1, 1)
                     , @tens = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 2, 1)
                     , @ones = SUBSTRING(@chunk, 3, 1)

                -- If twenty or less, use the word directly from @NumbersTable
                IF CONVERT(INT, @tensones) <= 20 OR @Ones='0' BEGIN
                    SET @outputString = (SELECT word 
                                              FROM @NumbersTable 
                                              WHERE @tensones = number)
                           + CASE @counter WHEN 1 THEN '' -- No name
                               WHEN 2 THEN ' thousand ' WHEN 3 THEN ' million '
                               WHEN 4 THEN ' billion '  WHEN 5 THEN ' trillion '
                               WHEN 6 THEN ' quadrillion ' WHEN 7 THEN ' quintillion '
                               WHEN 8 THEN ' sextillion '  WHEN 9 THEN ' septillion '
                               WHEN 10 THEN ' octillion '  WHEN 11 THEN ' nonillion '
                               WHEN 12 THEN ' decillion '  WHEN 13 THEN ' undecillion '
                               ELSE '' END
                                       + @outputString
                    END
                 ELSE BEGIN -- break down the ones and the tens separately

                     SET @outputString = ' ' 
                                    + (SELECT word 
                                            FROM @NumbersTable 
                                            WHERE @tens + '0' = number)
                                     + '-'
                                     + (SELECT word 
                                            FROM @NumbersTable 
                                            WHERE '0'+ @ones = number)
                           + CASE @counter WHEN 1 THEN '' -- No name
                               WHEN 2 THEN ' thousand ' WHEN 3 THEN ' million '
                               WHEN 4 THEN ' billion '  WHEN 5 THEN ' trillion '
                               WHEN 6 THEN ' quadrillion ' WHEN 7 THEN ' quintillion '
                               WHEN 8 THEN ' sextillion '  WHEN 9 THEN ' septillion '
                               WHEN 10 THEN ' octillion '  WHEN 11 THEN ' nonillion '
                               WHEN 12 THEN ' decillion '   WHEN 13 THEN ' undecillion '
                               ELSE '' END
                                    + @outputString
                END

                -- now get the hundreds
                IF @hundreds <> '0' BEGIN
                    SET @outputString  = (SELECT word 
                                              FROM @NumbersTable 
                                              WHERE '0' + @hundreds = number)
                                        + ' hundred ' 
                                        + @outputString
                END
            END

            SELECT @counter = @counter + 1
                 , @position = @position - 3

        END

        -- Remove any double spaces
        SET @outputString = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@outputString, '  ', ' ')))
        SET @outputstring = UPPER(LEFT(@outputstring, 1)) + SUBSTRING(@outputstring, 2, 8000)


        RETURN UPPER(@outputString)   -- return the result
        END
```

**For E.x :** SELECT dbo.Currency_ToWords(2500)

**OUTPUT:**   TWO THOUSAND FIVE HUNDRED

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the best solution would be to create a function which implements logic to convert a number into words. There are examples of this logic online, as an example: http://www.meadinkent.co.uk/xlnumberstext.htm it would just need to be converted to t-sql.

Then store the numeric value and derive the string value using a calculated field. The calculated field would call your new function and pass in the numeric column, the result would be the string representation of the number.

For a reference on calculated fields, have a look here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx

for a reference on creating functions, have a look here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx

Comment: Since you've *linked* to the relevant documentation, why not use the *correct* terminology? They're "Computed columns", not "calculated fields". In SQL, tables have columns.